# moving html range input within leaflet moves leaflet map rather than range input on Firefox

Tags: html, leaflet, geojson, timeline

I am using the [Leaflet timeline](https://github.com/skeate/Leaflet.timeline) to show a geojson with time attributes. When moving the slider on the range input on Chrome, the slider moves as expected. However, on Firefox, the leaflet map moves rather than the slider itself. An example of such application is found [here](http://skeate.github.io/Leaflet.timeline/earthquakes.html).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which Firefox version are you using ? I see your issue with Firefox 55 but it works with Firefox 57 (nightly). It seems like this issue will disapear in future version.

Comment: I am indeed using Firefox 55!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem comes from Firefox. It will be solved in version 57 as we can see in Firefox nightly.